# How to avoid Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks while using JSF and RichEditor

Tags: java, security, jsf, xss, richedit

I am using Rich Editor for user input text box on an all-JSF platform. I am trying to avoid XSS attacks on this text field.

The requirement is that

- the user can enter any character in the text box,
- the rich editor should display non-encoded values or the editor
  should not display `&lt;` for `<`,
- Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS) should be avoided.

So the problem is that since we have to display the values correctly, we put `escape=false` for outputtext, but it then becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks.

I tried using jsoup for filtering the HTML tags but it seems that the input automatically gets encoded and jsoup cannot be used.

So my questions are the following.

1. Is there a better approach of avoiding XSS attacks for rich editor
   with `escape=false`?
2. It looks like the text input is encoded when it reaches the save
   phase so I have not been able to filter with jsoup. How does JSF
   internally work in terms of encoding and decoding the text values.
   At which point can a script run?
3. If it happens to be encoded internally just after getting the input
   do I need to worry about XSS attack?
4. Also, there is a software Parse and it is being used to intercept a request. Is this a common tool for hacking and how this can be used to have a potential attack and how to avoid it in the present scenario. In specific, does it make any difference if a person intercepts the request as this software does for a normal request?

Comment: How have you tried jsoup there? Could you provide a brief example?

Answer (score 5):

You should implement a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) on any pages where you output the rich text.

This allows you to effectively stop inline script from being executed by the browser. It is currently [supported by](http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy) modern browsers such as Chrome and Firefox.

This is done by a HTTP response header from your page.

e.g.

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

will stop inline JavaScript from being executed if a user managed to inject it into your page (it will be ignored with a warning), but will allow script tags referencing either your own server or `https://apis.google.com`. This can be customised to your needs as required.

You could use this in combination with an HTML sanitizer to strip any malicious tags for a belt and braces approach and for protection for browsers that do not support CSP.

<strike>[Google have now implemented CSP in Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/reject-unexpected-content-security.html) to ensure any HTML email received cannot try anything sneaky to launch an XSS attack.</strike>

**Update:** At last time of checking, the CSP in Gmail appears to be pretty weak, allowing `script-src` to have `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval`:

```
content-security-policy: script-src https://clients4.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/ https://www.google.com/js/bg/ 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/ https://hangouts.google.com/ https://talkgadget.google.com/ https://*.talkgadget.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/installedApps/ https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/js/ https://docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/ https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/ https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/ https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/ https://apis.google.com/js/ https://clients1.google.com/complete/ https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/ https://ssl.gstatic.com/inputtools/js/ https://ssl.gstatic.com/cloudsearch/static/o/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/feedback/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/common_sharing/static/client/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/;frame-src https://clients4.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/ https://calendar.google.com/accounts/ 'self' https://accounts.google.com/ https://apis.google.com/u/ https://apis.google.com/_/streamwidgets/ https://clients6.google.com/static/ https://content.googleapis.com/static/ https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/ https://www.google.com/calendar/ https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ https://docs.google.com/ https://drive.google.com https://*.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ https://feedback.googleusercontent.com/resources/ https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/ https://support.google.com/inapp/ https://*.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr https://hangouts.google.com/ https://talkgadget.google.com/ https://*.talkgadget.google.com/ https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ https://plus.google.com/ https://wallet.google.com/gmail/ https://www.youtube.com/embed/ https://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/ https://clients5.google.com/ads/measurement/jn/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/ww/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/intl/ https://clients5.google.com/webstore/wall/ https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/ https://apis.google.com/additnow/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/promo/ https://notifications.google.com/ https://mail-payments.google.com/mail/payments/;report-uri https://mail.google.com/mail/cspreport;object-src https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/swfs/ https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/
```